# MFMessageComposeViewController doesn't do anything in my iPhone 4.x, why?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sms

I just upgraded to xcode 4.0.2, my iPhone is 4.3.5 and the `MFMessageComposeViewController` doesn't do anything.  It doesn't say "Can't send an SMS", it doesn't crash or abort, but it doesn't open the dialog to send the message either.  It simply does nothing.

```
-(void)sendSMS:(NSString *)message recipientList:(NSArray *)recipients
{
    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

        MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = 
             [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

        if (controller != nil) {
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

            controller.body = message;    
            controller.recipients = recipients;

            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
            // [controller release];   // If I really did this it would crash.
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I finally answered my own question. Now I want no one else to have to go through this.

I was calling this method from just an `NSObject`. It was a delegate to `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` but that made no difference. I had to move this method to my `MainViewController`, then it worked.